# Bulk import only works with 1 column csv file

Tags: sql-server

Whenever I try to import a CSV file into sql server with more than one column I get an error (well, nothing is imported). I know the file is terminated fine because it works with 1 column ok if I modify the file and table. I am limiting the rows so it never gets to the end, the line terminator is the correct and valid one (also shown by working when having 1 column only).

All I get is this and no errors

```
0 rows affected
```

I've also check all the other various questions like this and they all point to a bad end of file or line terminator, but all is well here...

I have tried quotes and no quotes. For example, I have a table with 2 columns of varchar(max). 
I run:

```
bulk insert mytable from 'file.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW=2,lastrow=4,rowterminator='\n')
```

My sample file is:

```
name,status 
TEST00040697,OK 
TEST00042142,OK 
TEST00042782,OK
TEST00043431,BT
```

If I drop a column then delete the second column in the csv ensuring it has the same line terminator \n, it works just fine.

I have also tried specifying the 'errorfile' parameter but it never seems to write anything or even create the file.

Comment: [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) you may need to set a `fielddelimiter=','` in your WITH clause as the default is a `tab`. The other option is to set `format='CSV'` which is a *comma separated values file compliant to the RFC 4180 standard.* which this probably fits.

Comment: thanks, see my answer I've just posted. I saw the entry 'FORMAT = 'CSV'' in the sql server documentation and assumed that meant it made the default CSV

Comment: mind you, adding 'WITH (format='CSV',' gives me an error "near 'format'"

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was embarrassing.

SQL Server in it's wisdom is using \t as the default field terminator for a CSV file, but I guess when the documentation says 'FORMAT = 'CSV'' it's an example and not the default.

If only it produced actual proper and useful error messages...